# Will List.map allocate a new List every time?

Tags: f#

Let's consider the following lists :

```
// 2 2 2 1 1 1
let xs = [2;2;2;1;1;1]

// 2 2 2 1 1 1
let xs' = List.map (fun x -> x) list

// 4 4 4 1 1 1
let xs'' = List.map (fun x -> x * x) list
```

Will `List.map` allocate a new list in the second case ? In the third case, will `xs` share the tail `[1;1;1]` with `xs''` ?

Comment: of course - how could it not as all the variables are in scope - the compiler couldn't necersarrily know that squaring does nothing to 1

Comment: @JohnPalmer I was thinking more of an optimization (at runtime) in the implementation of `List.map`. Will it be smart enough to share the same memory when it turns out that two tails are identical ?

Comment: Nope - the implementation is here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L85

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, it seems that it doesn't perform any optimization of this kind. Could you post your latest comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library tends to use simple implementations of this type of function.

As a result, this type of optimization isn't done.

The implementation can be found here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L85

Answer (score 2):

As John pointed out, optimization that you mentioned are not performed. If you really need it (which is highly unlikely), you can write your own version of map which shares the tail of a list, something like:

```
/// Returns a copy of 'a' which shares a common suffix with 'b'.
/// 'a' and 'b' must me of equal length.
let shareSuffixWith (a : 'a list) (b : 'a list) : 'a list =
    let discardLastNElements (n: int) (li : 'a list) = 
        List.take (li.Length - n) li
    let commonSuffix = 
        let zippedLists = List.zip a b
        let lastDifferentElemIndex = 
            List.tryFindIndexBack (fun (e1, e2) -> e1 <> e2) zippedLists
        match lastDifferentElemIndex with
        | None -> b
        | Some(index) -> List.skip (index+1) b
    let aPreffix = discardLastNElements commonSuffix.Length a
    aPreffix @ commonSuffix

/// Maps elements of a list using a mapping and shares 
/// common tail between input list and the result.
let mapAndShareSuffix (mapping :'T -> 'T) (li : 'T list) : 'T list = 
    let resultOfMap = List.map mapping li
    shareSuffixWith resultOfMap li
```

Note that:

- this implementation will perform more memory allocations then simply using `List.map` but some part of memory will be freed during Garbage Collection.
- F# lists does not take much space - only twice the size of a pointer per one element so the amount of memory that you gain by sharing a tail is minimal in most cases
- sharing list's tail takes processing and GC time
- the implementation above is sub-optimal and not idiomatic